# Drawing a cube in a glOrtho() view?

Tags: qt, opengl, cube, orthographic, orthogonal

I'm developing an 4 split viewer in OpenGL. One view is a perspective view, the other ones are for orthogonal projections (front, left, top).

I wrote a method that draws a cube from (-1,-1,-1) to (1,1,1) and it works well in the perspective view, but i can't get it to work in my views that use glOrtho(...).

Right now I set it up like this:

```
    glOrtho(0, width, height, 0, 0, 1);
```

The funny thing is, that the view doesn't show the cube at all. I implemented a border for the view in OpenGL which gets shown correctly though.

I'm using Qt and wrote a derived class of QGLWidget.

Comment: Assuming your viewport is also width by height, and width and height are your screen coordinates (say 800x600) that would make your cube 2 pixels wide in ortho view, no? also you near and far clipping planes are 0 and 1 which might clip the cube away depending on where the eye is located.

Comment: Makes sense. ;) So would you use glScale to make it bigger for the orthographic views only, or is there a more clever way?

Comment: @j.dog: You normally choose the limits set for the projection space volume to match those of your object. For your cube that would be glOrtho(-aspect, aspect, -1, 1, -1, 1), where aspect=viewport_width/viewport_height

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`glOrtho` define 6 clipping planes in the view space after the `model transform` and the `view transform`. So you should specify the parameters of glOrtho in the `Eye Space`, not the `Screen Space`. in your case, it should be `glOrtho(-width/(float)height, width/height, -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)` which assumes the `eye position` is in `(0.0, 0.0, 0.0)` and your `viewport` is `width` by `height`. the `NearVal` parameter of `glOrtho` should be negative if the near plane is behind the viewer(the eye position). You may want to man [glOrtho](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glOrtho.xml). the [4th Chapter](http://developer.nvidia.com/node/89) of `Cg tuturial` can give you a detailed information about the transformation of different coordinate spaces i.e. `Object Space`, `World Space`, `Eye Space`, `Clip space`, `Normalized Device Space` and `Window Space`.

Comment: So how would you change the eye position to say 100,120?

Comment: @paulm The eye position is relative to the models position, you can change the models's position to adjust it to the eye.